# What should I read before watching Daredevil Netflix series to avoid the series spoiling the comics?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil, daredevil-2015

I've read/know Daredevil history up to the beginning of the Bendis/Maleev run (I'm going to begin with it).
Is this enough? Does the series reference any "future" comics event?. If that's the case, up to what point should I read before watching the series?. Please no comics or series spoilers.

Comment: If you've gotten up to the Bendis ones (I believe those start mid-volume 2) you are *way* ahead of the MCU; e.g. the show hasn't even really gotten to the Karen Page relationship yet.

Answer (score 5):

The *Daredevil* TV Show is part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe, and while it takes a few nods from the comics (I believe Fisk's history is largely based off David Mack's stories), it does not specifically reference anything from the comics, nor does it spoil any specific storylines.